# How can I get merge table column resample in python?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pandas-groupby, pandas-resample

I have a question handling dataframe in pandas.

I really don't know what to do.

Could you check this problem?

[df1]

[image]

This is first dataframe and I want to get second dataframe.
Like this[image]

I got a index value DATE(Week), DATE(Month) using resample method in pandas.
but I don't know merge the table like second table.
so please check this question. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

What I have understood from your question is that you want to diversify `DATE` column to its nearest `week` and `month`, so if that is the case you need not have to create two separate DataFrame, there is an easier way to do it using [DateOffsets](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html)

```
#taking sample from your data
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import *

>>d = {'DATE': ['2019-01-14', '2019-01-16', '2019-02-19'], 'TX_COST': [156800, 157000, 150000]}
>>df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>df
         DATE  TX_COST
0  2019-01-14   156800
1  2019-01-16   157000
2  2019-02-19   150000

#convert Date column to datetime format

df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])


#as per your requirement set weekday=6 that is sunday as the week ending date

>>> df['WEEK'] = df['DATE'] + Week(weekday=6)
>>> df
        DATE  TX_COST       WEEK
0 2019-01-14   156800 2019-01-20
1 2019-01-16   157000 2019-01-20
2 2019-02-19   150000 2019-02-24

#use month offset to round the date to nearest month end

>>> df['MONTH'] = df['DATE'] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()
>>> df
        DATE  TX_COST       WEEK      MONTH
0 2019-01-14   156800 2019-01-20 2019-01-31
1 2019-01-16   157000 2019-01-20 2019-01-31
2 2019-02-19   150000 2019-02-24 2019-02-28
```

This will create the DataFrame which you require

Comment: Thank you so much, but I wondering about Week(weekday=6) meaning..Could you check this code?

Comment: So when you do ```offsets.Week()``` it will add 7 days from the given date and will give you that date as week. But when you do ```Week(weekday=6)``` then ```weekday=0``` is ```Monday``` and ```weekday=6``` is ```Sunday``` so this ```Week(weekday=6)``` will round the week to the nearest ```sunday``` which is your requirement. You can go through the doc link which I have shared that will clear all your doubts

Comment: I want df['WEEK'] = df['DATE'] + Week(weekday=6) this point. I'm really thank your comments.

Comment: Great I have edited my answer just for your requirement

Comment: Thank you, but Week(weekday=6) code dosen't work.

Comment: It does work for me what is the error you are getting, have imported this ```from pandas.tseries.offsets import *``` in your code

Comment: Oh, yes. Thank you so much!